# Kafka-stream : How to re-key a stream by selecting key from a list of values

Tags: lambda, apache-kafka-streams

I have an object A :

```
public class A {
  String id;
  List<String> otherIds;
  SomeOtherObject object;
}
```

I have a kafka stream which looks like :

```
KStream<Integer, A> inputStream
```

I need to re-key this **inputStream** stream so that it should be now:

```
KStream<String, A> newStream
```

Where the  key part of the newStream is **otherId**  from **A.otherIds**.

### **For an example**

```
Let's say, A is like : { id:1, otherIds:[ "ab","bc","ca"],OtherObject: obj1}.

And inputStream if like <1,A>,

Then the newStream should have:
<"ab",A>
<"bc", A>
<"ca",A>
```

### Roughly, to get an idea on what I am trying is:

```
 KStream<String,  A> newStream =
        inputStream
                .map((key,val) ->
                                val.getOtherIds().stream().forEach(e->
                        KeyValue.pair(e,val))
                );
```

Is there a way to do it ( Rekeying by selecting key from list of the values)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to split a single record into multiple, you should use `flatMap()` instead of `map()`. `map()` is a 1:1 operation while `flatMap()` is 1:n.

To return multiple `KeyValue` pairs, your `flatMap()` can `return` a `List<KevValue>` for example (any other `Collection<KeyValue>` type would work, too).

Answer (score 3):

### **From the suggestion of @Matthias, I did it this way(it worked):**

```
KStream<String,  A> newStream =
        inputStream
                .flatMap((key,A)->{

                    return A.getOtherIdsList().stream().map( id ->{
                        return KeyValue.pair(id, A);

                            })
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                 });
```

Thank you